# Unable to reproduce: C++ Vector performance advantages over C# List performance

Tags: c#, c++, performance, vector

At Microsoft's BUILD conference Herb Sutter explained that C++ has "Real Arrays" and C#/Java languages do not have the same or sort of.

I was sold on that. You can watch the full talk here http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-661

Here is a quick snapshot of the slide where he described this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQaiF.png

But I wanted to see how much difference will I make.

So I wrote very naive programs for testing, which create a large vector of strings from a file with lines ranging from 5 characters to 50 characters.

Link to the file:

```
www (dot) dropbox.com/s/evxn9iq3fu8qwss/result.txt
```

Then I accessed them in sequence.

I did this exercise in both C# and C++.

> Note: I made some modifications, removed the copying in the loops as suggested. 
>   Thank you for helping me to understand the Real arrays.

In C# I used both List and ArrayList because ArrayList it is deprecated in favor of List.

Here are the results on my dell laptop with Core i7 processor:

```
count       C# (List<string>)   C# (ArrayList)     C++   

1000           24 ms              21 ms             7 ms       
10000         214 ms             213 ms            64 ms     
100000  2 sec 123 ms       2 sec 125 ms           678 ms
```

---

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;
namespace CSConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int count;
            bool success = int.TryParse(args[0], out count);

            var watch = new Stopwatch();
            System.IO.StreamReader isrc = new System.IO.StreamReader("result.txt");

            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            while (!isrc.EndOfStream)
            {
                list.Add(isrc.ReadLine());
            }
            double k = 0;
            watch.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                ArrayList temp = new ArrayList();
                for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
                {
                   // temp.Add(list[j]);
                    k++;
                }
            }

            watch.Stop();
            TimeSpan ts = watch.Elapsed;

            //Console.WriteLine(ts.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Hours: {0} Miniutes: {1} Seconds: {2} Milliseconds: {3}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine(k);
            isrc.Close();
        }


    }
}
```

---

C++ code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point time_now()
{
    return std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
}

float time_elapsed(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point const & start)
{

    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(time_now() - start).count();
    //return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<float>>(time_now() - start).count();
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv [])
{
    int  count = _wtoi(argv[1]);

    vector<string> vs;
    fstream fs("result.txt", fstream::in);
    if (!fs) return -1;

    char* buffer = new char[1024];
    while (!fs.eof())
    {
        fs.getline(buffer, 1024);
        vs.push_back(string(buffer, fs.gcount()));
    }
    double k = 0;
    auto const start = time_now();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        vector<string> vs2;
        vector<string>::const_iterator iter;
        for (iter = vs.begin(); iter != vs.end(); iter++)
        {
            //vs2.push_back(*iter);
            k++;
        }
    }

    auto const elapsed = time_elapsed(start);
    cout << elapsed << endl;
    cout << k;
    fs.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you tag this Java? Note also that the "msbuild" tag description is *"MSBuild (Microsoft Build Engine) is a platform for building applications."*

Comment: I only tested with C# but the above argument applies equally to both Java and C# according to the talk.

Comment: What flags did you pass when compiling?

Comment: No additional flags except building in release mode in Visual Studio.

Comment: Also you realize that a `vector<string>` on the "stack" vs. the "heap" are basically the same thing for this test, right? A 'vector's data array is *always* on the heap, it doesn't matter where the structure itself is. Also C# List is not equivalent to ArrayList. I don't know C# and don't know what type of list it is but from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) *"In deciding whether to use the List<T> or ArrayList class, both of which have similar functionality, remember that the List<T> class performs better in most cases ..."*.

Comment: Also this is meaningless unless you use similar compiler optimizations for both. But at the bare minimum, use a C# ArrayList (it doesn't matter that it's deprecated -- it's silly to compare performance of different data structures), make sure their capacities and growth factors are the same, and drop your C++ heap test, it's pointless. You have *way* too many variables for this to yield any kind of interesting results.

Comment: @GangadharChowdaryPayyavula: In C++, unless you use custom allocators, a `std::string` allocates its buffer on the heap (even if the instance itself is on the stack, which won't be for you.) This means that a `vector<string>` will have its data scattered all over the memory, and *won't be contiguous* and therefore, won't be any more efficient than the equivalent C#. The fact that C++ is ten times slower, just means that you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @GangadharChowdaryPayyavula: Oh, and if you want people to be able to replicate your results, either put your data file online (so we can rerun with your exact input) or use a file that can already be found online.

Comment: @yzt I have added the link to test file in the above description.

Comment: FWIW an array of value types in C# is pretty much what Herb Sutter refers to as a "real array".

Comment: So what was the question, actually?

Comment: This slide is completely misleading, because C++ classes behave more like C# structs. Their contents are passed by value by default, like with C# struct arrays (which *are* contiguous). "Class types" in C# are actually called "reference types", and are passed by reference. So the comment that it's not possible to have contiguous blocks "for class types" should instead be "not possible for types passed by reference", which applies to C++ equally (if you have an array of references in C++, it won't be contiguous).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The differences found by your sample program has nothing to do with lists or their structure.

It's because in C#, strings are a reference type, whereas in C++ code, you are using them as a value type.

For example:

```
string a = "foo bar baz";
string b = a;
```

Assigning `b = a` is just copying the pointer.

This follows through into lists. Adding a string to a C# list is just adding a pointer to the list. In your main loop, you create N lists, all of which just contain pointers to the same strings.

Because you're using strings by value in C++ however, it has to copy them each time.

```
vector<string> vs2;
vector<string>::const_iterator iter;
for (iter = vs.begin(); iter != vs.end(); iter++)
{
   vs2.push_back(*iter); // STRING IS COPIED HERE
}
```

This code is actually making copies of each string. You end up with copies of all the strings, and will use a lot more memory. This is slower for obvious reasons.

If you rewrite the loop as follows:

```
vector<string*> vs2;
for (auto& s : vs)
{
    vs2.push_back(&(s));
}
```

Then you're now creating lists-of-pointers not lists-of-copies and are on equal footing with C#.

On my system, the C# program runs with N of 1000 in about **138 milliseconds**, and the C++ one runs in **44 milliseconds**, a clear win to C++.

---

Commentary:

One of the main benefits of C++ vectors as per herb sutter's picture, is that the memory layout can be contiguous (i.e. all the items are stuck next to each other in memory).
You'll never see this work with a `std::string` however, as strings require dynamic memory allocation (you can't stick a load of strings next to each other in an array because each string has a different length)

This would give a large benefit if you wanted to quickly iterate through them all, as it's much friendlier to CPU caches, but the tradeoff is that you have to copy all the items to get them into the list.

Here's an example which better illustrates it:

C# Code:

```
class ValueHolder {
    public int tag;
    public int blah;
    public int otherBlah;

    public ValueHolder(int t, int b, int o)
    { tag = t; blah = b; otherBlah = o; }
};

static ValueHolder findHolderWithTag(List<ValueHolder> buffer, int tag) {
    // find holder with tag i
    foreach (var holder in buffer) {
        if (holder.tag == tag)
            return holder;
    }
    return new ValueHolder(0, 0, 0);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int MAX = 99999;

    int  count = 1000; // _wtoi(argv[1]);
    List<ValueHolder> vs = new List<ValueHolder>();
    for (int i = MAX; i >= 0; i--) {
        vs.Add(new ValueHolder(i, 0, 0)); // construct valueholder with tag i, blahs of 0
    }

    var watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        ValueHolder found = findHolderWithTag(vs, i);
        if (found.tag != i)
            throw new ArgumentException("not found");
    }

    watch.Stop();
    TimeSpan ts = watch.Elapsed;
    Console.WriteLine("Hours: {0} Miniutes: {1} Seconds: {2} Milliseconds: {3}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds);
}
```

C++ Code:

```
class ValueHolder {
public:
    int tag;
    int blah;
    int otherBlah;

    ValueHolder(int t, int b, int o) : tag(t), blah(b), otherBlah(o) { }
};

const ValueHolder& findHolderWithTag(vector<ValueHolder>& buffer, int tag) {
    // find holder with tag i
    for (const auto& holder : buffer) {
        if (holder.tag == tag)
            return holder;
    }
    static ValueHolder empty{ 0, 0, 0 };
    return empty;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const int MAX = 99999;

    int  count = 1000; // _wtoi(argv[1]);
    vector<ValueHolder> vs;
    for (int i = MAX; i >= 0; i--) {
        vs.emplace_back(i, 0, 0); // construct valueholder with tag i, blahs of 0
    }

    auto const start = time_now();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        const ValueHolder& found = findHolderWithTag(vs, i);
        if (found.tag != i) // need to use the return value or compiler will optimize away
            throw "not found";
    }

    auto const elapsed = time_elapsed(start);
    cout << elapsed << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

We already know from the original question that creating a bunch of duplicate lists would be much faster in C# than in C++, but what about searching the list instead?

Both programs are just doing a stupid linear list-scan in a simple attempt to show this.

On my PC, the C++ version runs in **72ms** and the C# one takes **620ms**. Why the speed increase? Because of the "real arrays".

All the C++ `ValueHolders` are stuck next to eachother in the `std::vector`. When the loop wants to read the next one, this means it's most likely already in the CPU cacue.

The C# ValueHolders are in all kinds of random memory locations, and the list just contains pointers to them. When the loop wants to read the next one, it is almost certainly *not* in the CPU cache, so we have to go and read it. Memory access is slow, hence the C# version takes nearly 10x as long.

If you change the C# ValueHolder from `class` to `struct`, then the C# List can stick them all next to eachother in memory, and the time drops to **161ms**. Buuut now it has to make copies when you're inserting into the list.

The problem for C# is that there are many many situations where you can't or don't want to use a struct, whereas in C++ you have more control over this kind of thing.

PS: Java doesn't have structs, so you can't do this at all. You're stuck with the 10x as slow cache unfriendly version

Comment: +1 for the hidden clue _"If you change the C# `ValueHolder` from `class` to `struct`, then the C# List can stick them all next to each other in memory, and the time drops to 161ms. But now it has to make copies"_ I think this should be made much more prominent in the answer, because ValueType[] are very much the closest thing in C#. $0.02

Comment: If you really care about performance and still want to use a kind of `vector<string>` you could create a custom string type based on `std::basic_string` with a **dedicated allocator**, that would provide continuous memory regions (next to each other). That should help for locality and improve cache utilization.

Comment: Note that for small strings, the Small String Optimization could make it a "value", as it would embed its data, instead of pointing to another memory chunk... But then, not all strings are supposed to be small.

Comment: I tried replacing `foreach` with an explicit `for` loop in the C# version to see what difference it would make, and running time dropped from ~550ms to ~130ms (with `ValueHolder` declared as `class`). Switching from `List<T>` to an array `T[]` resulted in running time dropping again to ~90ms. Then I changed `ValueHolder` to a `struct`, change the method to return the value as `ref` parameter, and also ran the loop once before starting the measurement to ensure everything was JITted. Then it dropped to ~68ms (my i7 laptop). x86 release build. Piece of cake! :-D

Comment: tl;dr In most benchmarks I've seen, C# can be made to run almost as fast as C++ (difference shouldn't be more than 10%), as long as you waste a bunch of time doing microoptimizations like these and profiling. And avoiding the legacy x64 compiler like the plague (I hope RyuJIT is going to fix that). And that's compared to MS C++ builds of course, since GCC seems to do a better job in benchmarks.

Comment: so structs are passed within the cache and classes are passed with the ram. <-- from 0-100% how much is this statement correct?

Comment: @sehe Indeed, `ValueType[]` with `struct ValueType` *is* a "real array" i.e. contiguous in memory. There is a much larger difference between C++ or C# and Java because the latter only has "real" arrays of built-ins – everything else will require references and will be boxed in the worst case – even if generics are used, which in Java are little more than syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 7):

While C# `string` and C++ `std::string` share a name, and both are ordered collections of character types, they are very different otherwise.

`std::string` is a mutable container, C#'s `string` is immutable.  This means the data in two C# `string`s can be shared: copying a C# `string` duplicates a pointer (aka reference), and does knock-on lifetime management work.  Duplicating a `std::string` copies the contents (copy on write C++ `std::string` are not legal).

To create a more similar set of C++ code, store `std::shared_ptr<const std::string>` in your `vector`s.  And when you stuff the duplicate `vector`s, make sure you only copy the smart pointers.  Now you have (smart) pointers to immutable data, just like C#.

Note that this will improve copy performance probably in C++, but will make most other operations slower (if want to you edit the `std::string` you now have to copy the entire thing, then modify the copy, and read does an extra pointer dereference).

```
struct immutable_string {
  immutable_string() = default;
  immutable_string(const&) = default;
  immutable_string(&&) = default;
  immutable_string& operator=(const&) = default;
  immutable_string& operator=(&&) = default;

  immutable_string( std::string s ):data( std::make_shared<std::string>(std::move(s)) ) {}

  std::string const& get() const { if (data) return *data; return *empty_string(); }
  std::string get() && {
    if (!data) return {};
    if (data->use_count()==1) return std::move( const_cast<std::string&>(*data) );
    return *data;
  }
  template<class... Args>
  void emplace( Args&&... args ) {
    data = std::make_shared<std::string>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  template<class F>
  void modify( F&& f ) {
    std::string tmp = std::move(*this).get();
    std::forward<F>(f)(tmp);
    emplace(std::move(tmp));
  }
private:
  std::shared_ptr<const std::string> data;
  static std::shared_ptr<const std::string> empty_string() {
    static auto nothing = std::make_shared<const std::string>();
    return nothing;
  }
};
```

this gives us COW.  To edit, call `immutable_string s; s.modify( [&](std::string& s){` *code goes here* `});`.