# Swift: Protocol vs. Struct vs. Class

Tags: ios, class, struct, swift, protocols

I am starting to learn the Swift language and am having trouble wrapping my head around Protocols, Structs and Classes.

I come from the Android side of programming, so I believe that Swift Protocols are basically Java Interfaces?

What would be proper use cases for each of these?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

These analogies are not "exactly" correct, but this is the gist of it as I understand it

1. Yes, Protocols are effectively like interfaces
2. Classes are classes, like in Java/Android, and pretty much any other language
3. Structs are like classes, but they are passed by-value (copied) when passing them from one variable/function to another.
   If you're familiar with C# at all, it's implementation of structs is very similar.

Eg:

```
class Foo {
   ...
}

let x = Foo()
let z = x
```

At this point x and z both refer to the same Object in memory, there is only one `Foo` object

```
struct Bar {
   ...
}

let a = Bar()
let b = a
```

When assigning b, a is copied (think of basically copying the memory block). At this point, there are two independent `Bar` objects in memory and modifying one doesn't affect the other.

Why is this useful? Sometimes you don't want a shared reference, but mostly for performance reasons. Because structs don't have to all refer to the same object, they don't have to be allocated on the heap. They can instead often be allocated on the stack, which is *much* faster. Also arrays of structs can be implemented as one big contiguous block of memory which means it's much friendlier on the CPU cache if you want to iterate through it all.

Swift isn't garbage collected, but for garbage collected languages like C# this can mean the garbage collector doesn't have to deal with a lot of objects that it might otherwise have to. Even in swift the struct copying means it can avoid doing the `Retain`/`Release` behind the scenes neccessary for ARC, which can help a lot.

The primary use case for structs is when you have lots of immutable "simple data" like a Vector (set of 3 floating point values)

Comment: Very well explained. That answers my question, thanks!

Comment: Note that Array, String, and Dictionary are all structs in Swift. The standard library in general leans heavily towards structs and protocols rather than classes.

Comment: "let a = Bar() let b = a. When assigning b, a is copied (think of basically copying the memory block). At this point, there are two independent Bar objects in memory and modifying one doesn't affect the other." Not true in implementation. But in use effectively true. When assignment happens for a struct a reference is made to the original. You only get a copy when you actually change b. This is known as copy on write. It saves memory until it's actually needed during run time.

Comment: The only reason I bring it up is new programmers to swift might think structs are very memory intensive when being passed around a lot. However because of the copy on write a spect they are not.

Comment: I am a newbie: "Also arrays of structs can be implemented as one big contiguous block of memory which means it's much friendlier on the CPU cache if you want to iterate through it all." **What? Why?**

Comment: @Honey - Scroll down to the "Commentary" section on this answer. It might help explain a few things if you can get past the C# and C++ code in it:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22926046/unable-to-reproduce-c-vector-performance-advantages-over-c-sharp-list-perform/22926637#22926637

Comment: @OrionEdwards Thanks. That was probably the longest delay between 2 comments. Based on you other answer its as if reaching out to multiple pointers is like finding bringing multiple books from multiple rooms while multiple values are pulling them all from one shelf which is right next to my desk( the CPU). ( I don't know what lists are. I haven't studied them yet. So I was only able to come up with this gross analogy. Not sure if it's a good one)