# Swift OptionSetType resets custom properties

Tags: swift, protocols

I want to create an OptionSetType with a custom property added to the struct:

```
struct Options: OptionSetType {

    let rawValue: Int

    init(rawValue: Int) {
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }

    // some option
    static let opt = Options(rawValue: 1)

    // custom stored property
    var a = 0

}
```

The custom property gets reset every time the OptionSetType protocol's methods `insert` or `remove` are called:

```
var x: Options = []

x.rawValue // => 0
x.a = 1 // => 1

x.insert(.opt)
x.rawValue // => 1
x.a // => 0 <-- a is changed
```

My guess is that `insert(_:)` does something like this:

```
self = Options(rawValue: newValueWithInsertedOption)
```

Which resets the struct.
Is there any way of keeping the stored value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this seems to be impossible, workaround is to wrap the `OptionSetType` in another custom struct/class, which contains the custom properties.

Answer (score 0):

Structs are passed by value (copying), Classes by reference. This can sure be a pain to keep straight.

When you run `x.insert(.opt)`, you're initializing a new struct with`Options(rawValue: 1)` and copying the original value of `a` rather than carrying through the reference that may have been previously set.

So, though you've previously set `a` to `1` in your code, the insert afterwards initializes a new struct and `a` is then back to `0`.

Check out this fine explanation of struct value passing for more info:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26006268/4228039

Structs aren't really designed for keeping stored references that are continued on each initialization, but more for setting up initial values that are passed in. Classes would work better for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know structs are value types, but normally when you call a `mutating` method on a struct, all values in the struct will be copied as well. For `OptionSetType` this is not the case when calling `insert`. The only way I can think of to make this work is to create a wrapper that contains the `Options` struct, but I would really like a cleaner solution